# Failure while Loading Parquet file to Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-data-factory, parquet, azure-synapse

I load pre-generated Parquet files (present in Azure Blob Storage) to Azure synapse tables everyday. The job ran successfully until yesterday, but all of sudden it's failing.

Note: A Test Copy Job Executes Successfully when Parquet File is Loaded to a CSV in the same Blob Storage.

Error Message while loading Parquet File to Synapse:

```
Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error occurred when invoking java, message:   
 java.io.IOException:Error reading summaries total entry:6   
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallelUsingSummaryFiles(ParquetFileReader.java:190)   
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.<init>(ParquetReader.java:112)   
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.<init>(ParquetReader.java:45)   
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader$Builder.build(ParquetReader.java:20  
2)   
com.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetBatchReaderBridge.open(ParquetBatchReaderBridge.java:62)   
com.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetFileBridge.createReader(ParquetFileBridge.java:22)   
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError total entry:9   
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)  
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.runAllInParallel(ParquetFileReader.java:227)   
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallelUsingSummaryFiles(ParquetFileReader.java:185)  
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.<init>(ParquetReader.java:112)   
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.<init>(ParquetReader.java:45)   
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader$Builder.build(ParquetReader.java:202)   
com.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetBatchReaderBridge.open(ParquetBatchReaderBridge.java:62)   
com.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetFileBridge.createReader(ParquetFileBridge.java:22) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:null total entry:24   
org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)   
org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:104)   
org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:86)   
org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)   
org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)   
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)  
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:248)   
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:763)   
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:748)   
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:621)  
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2753)  
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2745)  
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2611)   
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)   
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:354)   
org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)  
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readSummaryMetadata(ParquetFileReader.java:360)   
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$1.call(ParquetFileReader.java:158)   
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$1.call(ParquetFileReader.java:155) java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)  
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)   
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:begin 0, end 3, length 1 total entry:27 java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3116)  
java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1885)   
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:49)   org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)   org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:104)   
org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:86)   org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)   org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:248)   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:763)   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:748)   
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:621) org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2753) org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2745)   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2611)   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:169)   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:354)   org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readSummaryMetadata(ParquetFileReader.java:360)   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$1.call(ParquetFileReader.java:158)   org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader$1.call(ParquetFileReader.java:155)  
java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)   
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)   
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)   
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)   .,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.ParquetTransferPlugin,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.JniExt.JavaBridgeException,Message=,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.HiveOrcBridge,
```

Comment: Hi Suny Sinha, More details required to identify the problem.  Kindly raise a support ticket.

Comment: Hi ! this issue has been resolved. t was found that the JVM has been uninstalled on the Azure VM Leading to Issues